# How to set the code selection programatically in AvalonEdit?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, avalonedit

I'm using AvalonEdit in a Microsoft Surface application. Since the Contacts are handled a little bit different there than in a normal WPF application, I want to set the code selection programatically.

By code selection I mean this part of the code whichs background is changed if the user select it with the mouse.

I now the DocumentLine or the VisualLine where the selection should start and where it should end. But how can I now make this selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.Editor` is `AvalonEdit` object, `selectionStart` is offset relative to the start of the text being edited.

```
        this.Editor.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
        this.Editor.SelectionEnd = selectionStart + selectionLength;
```